# Sum and count list of dict in pure python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

i need help.

**I have a list o dict:**

```
[{"title": "Report 1", "value": 1000, "commission": 2000, "user": "user_1"},

{"title": "Report 2", "value": 500, "commission": 300, "user": "user_1"},

{"title": "Report 3", "value": 1500, "commission": 300, "user": "user_2"}]
```

**I need to sum numeric values, and group by user and total report per user**

```
[{"value": 1500, "commission": 2300, "user": "user_1", "total": 2},

{"value": 1500, "commission": 300, "user": "user_2", "total": 1}]
```

**OBS:** In pure python

Comment: please make an attempt before we can help you debug

Comment: The question is very clear and contains all of the information needed to answer it.   Moreover, the user should not be forced to provide an attempt if they do not understand the basics of how the capability works, if the goal is to have high quality questions.  The comments and hold therefore seem inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a very simple iteration method.

**Demo:**

```
data = [{"title": "Report 1", "value": 1000, "commission": 2000, "user": "user_1"},
{"title": "Report 2", "value": 500, "commission": 300, "user": "user_1"},
{"title": "Report 3", "value": 1500, "commission": 300, "user": "user_2"}]

d = {}
for i in data:
    if i['user'] not in d:
        d[i["user"]] = {"value": i["value"], "commission": i["commission"], "user": i['user'], "total": 1}
    else:
        d[i["user"]]["value"] += i["value"]
        d[i["user"]]["commission"] += i["commission"]
        d[i["user"]]["total"] += 1
print(d.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[{'commission': 300, 'total': 1, 'user': 'user_2', 'value': 1500}, {'commission': 2300, 'total': 2, 'user': 'user_1', 'value': 1500}]
```